# read non-English file

Tags: c#, .net

when I try to read file which written in arabic format ,I get only last line ...what's the problem.

The code:

```
// Read the file and display it line by line in text box
System.IO.StreamReader file =
   new System.IO.StreamReader("arabic.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    txtfile[count] = line;
    textBox1.Text = txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine;

    count++;
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the format of the file.  You are replacing the textbox's text with each line as you read it.

Comment: I would also advise to change the Data structure in which you're using to save up the data. seems like you're using a dynamically-created array (txtfile) - you should use 'ArrayList' or anything similar instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try `textBox1.Text += txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: thank you very mush for your advise  ,I discovered this trivial error .what I try now and I  cant when the array display its empty no thing display ??

Answer (score 2):

The reason you see only the last line in your TextBox is because you're not appending the text.

Try using

```
 textBox1.Text += txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine;
```

Instead of

```
textBox1.Text = txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try,

```
TextBox1.Text=System.IO.File.ReadAllText("arabic.txt",Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
 textBox1.Text = txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine
```

try

```
 textBox1.Text += txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
       new System.IO.StreamReader("arabic.txt", Encoding.UTF8); 
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
    { 
        txtfile[count] = line; 
        textBox1.Text += txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine;


        count++; 
    } 

    file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't add the lines to the textbox, you just set it. So only the last line will be shown. Change your code like that:

```
// Read the file and display it line by line in text box 
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("arabic.txt", Encoding.UTF8); 
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
{ 
    txtfile[count] = line; 
    textBox1.Text += txtfile[count]+Environment.NewLine; 

    count++; 
} 

file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd read the file to a collection - e.g a List<> - before assigning it to my Textbox rather than setting it to the TextBox directly after reading (everything not shown in the TextBox - ie. everything after the last line - is effectively lost).

Also, when using StreamReaders, use the using statement; it cleans up after itself removing the need of calling StreamReader.Close() when we're done:

```
public List<string> ReadTextFile(string filePath)
{
    var ret = new List<string>();

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException();

    // Using the "using" directive removes the need of calling StreamReader.Close
    // when we're done with the object - it closes itself.
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            ret.Add(line);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

You could also use an array, or any other collection. Using this, you could fill your TextBox element like so:

```
var fileContents = ReadTextFile("arabic.txt");

foreach (var s in fileContents)
    textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0}{1}", s, Environment.NewLine);
```

While still having a local copy of the text file in fileContents.

Comment: thanks very mush for your advice. i write it directily to text box just to insure it can read and display arabic litter .  but i want this arabic file to search in it about word enter in text box from user .  can you palse help my in that . i notice you use        Format("{0}{1}"==> what is that??

Comment: String.Format replaces each format item in a specified string with the text equivalent of a corresponding object's value. Meaning that if you would do for example `string.Format("Value: {0}, obj.Value");`, assuming obj.Value is 10, the output would be `Value: 10`. `{0}` is simply a wildcard for the object value, which is specified in the params of the method.